# Exporting hclust cluster membership

Tags: r, hclust

I am new to R. I am trying to do hclust and export the cluster membership. I have used the following. Is this correct or is there a better way?

```
FCtable1<-as.matrix(read.delim("table1.txt", row.names=1, header=TRUE, sep="\t"))
Disttab1<-dist(FCtable1, method="euclidean")
Hclustout1<-hclust(Disttab1, method="average")
clustnumber<- cutree(Hclustout1, h=1000)
tab1clustn <-data.frame(FCtable1, clustnumber)
write.table(tab1clustn,  file=" tab1clustn.xls", row.names=T, sep="\t")
```

Thanks
R

Comment: Assuming that tab1clustn <-data.frame(table1, clustnumber) should be tab1clustn <-data.frame(FCtable1, clustnumber), it should work. You can also specify the number of clusters instead of the height in cutree().

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. Yes, table1 is a typo.